# probe global variables to call inside function

Tags: r, function, global-variables

I want to pass variables within the `.Globalenv` when inside a function. Basically concatenate x number of data frames into a matrix.

Here is some dummy code;

```
Alpha <- data.frame(lon=124.9167,lat=1.53333)

Alpha_2 <- data.frame(lon=3.13333, lat=42.48333)

Alpha_3 <- data.frame(lon=-91.50667, lat=27.78333)

myfunc <- function(x){
     vars <- ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern=x)
     mat <- as.matrix(rbind(vars[1], vars[2], vars[3]))
     return(mat)
}
```

When calling `myfunc('Alpha')` I would like the same thing to be returned as when you run;

```
as.matrix(rbind(Alpha, Alpha_2, Alpha_3)

        lon      lat
1 124.91670  1.53333
2   3.13333 42.48333
3 -91.50667 27.78333
```

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: +1 for the easily reproducible example.  It's awesome when I can just copy paste code and be ready to go without having to mess with `read.table`, etc.  It happens so rarely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get` to retrieve variables by name.  We do this here in a loop with `lapply`, and then use `rbind` to bind them together.

```
myfunc <- function(x){
  vars <- ls(.GlobalEnv, pattern=x)
  df <- do.call(rbind, mget(vars, .GlobalEnv))  # courtesy @Roland
  return(df)
}
myfunc("Alpha")

#         lon      lat
# 1 124.91670  1.53333
# 2   3.13333 42.48333
# 3 -91.50667 27.78333
```

Note, in practice, you probably want to check that the variables that match the pattern actually are what you think they are, but this gives you the rough tools you want.

Old version (2nd line of func):

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, get, envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: You could use `mget`.